# Programmatically get city/state of MacBook from command line?

Tags: shell, command-line

Is there a way to get the location or city/state from the MacBook programmatically?  It doesn't have to be very accurate, just wondering if it's possible.

Something without remotely accessing a GeoIP service.

Answer (score 1):

**In two parts:** (a bit of a hack)

**Get your ipaddress:**

```
ifconfig | grep "inet addr" | grep -v '127\.0\.0\.1' | tr ':' ' ' | awk '{print $3}'
```

**Look up your address with a table:**
http://ipinfodb.com/linux_script.php

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** (original response further down)
I've begun a GitHub repo to do exactly as described below: https://github.com/inspector-g/getloc

Due to having limited time today, it was easier/faster to just use typical external IP geolocation tricks. It works great on all the machines I've tested it on. However, I did place all the necessary CoreLocation stubs for future use. If I get more time this week, I might implement the third-party MapKit for Mac OS X (as mentioned below).

**Original response**
There are no built-in command line programs to do this. You could make a simple one yourself, by building a Cocoa command line program in Xcode, as following...

As of Mac OS 10.6, you can get the user's lat/long location with `CLLocationManager`. In the class you'd like to be the delegate of location info:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

With `locationManager` being a member of the class. In order to receive messages from `CLLocationManager`, your delegate class will need to implement the following methods:

```
-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager
        didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation*)newLocation
        fromLocation:(CLLocation*)oldLocation;

-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager
        didFailWithError:(NSError*)error;
```

Now that you're all set up and receiving `CLLocation` instances in these methods, how do you get the city, state, or other geographic info from the latitude and longitude data in `CLLocation`? You don't! Apple doesn't provide a reverse geocoder for Mac OS X (only iOS).

However, to fill the gap, a pretty decent library to match the features of MapKit on iOS has been released: http://github.com/Oomph/MacMapKit

It's meant to match the features of MapKit, in fact, and does a pretty good job. Best of luck :)

Comment: (In fact, now that I think about it, I might just make this little program and post it on GitHub...)